# How can I change to a different view within a different navigation controller than I'm in at the moment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tab bar controller and a navigation controller. Each tab bar item has its own navigation controller and a few views within those.

I want to programitically switch to another view in a another navigation controller and have the correct corresponding tab bar item selected.

Is this possible, if so can you show me how ?

Heres some typical lines I'm using at the moment within the same navigation controllers.

```
[delegate.settingsNavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
[delegate.reportNavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

When ever I try this, nothing happens, I stay in the current view, however if I were to tap another navigation button and the view I'd tried (with code) wasn't normally the first view, that view would show first.

So it is changing the view within the navigation controller, but its not showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to switch to the new tab:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = settingsTabIndex;
[delegate.settingsNavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ahh great, but what if I want to select the first view that would be shown the first time the tab bar button was pressed ?

Comment: Just call [delegate.settingsNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] instead of -pushViewController:animated:.  Here's the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934